# BlackBerry Application compatibility wiht smartphone and normal phone

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am new to BB development.recently i have developed a simple application using JDE eclipse plugin ( Blackberry JRE 5.0.0.0 ). I have tested this simple application on default simulator i.e. BlackBerry Simulator 9550 , a smartphone simulator.

But when i have tried to test this same application on other simulators i.e. 8520,8900,9630,9700 ( simulators only with keypads, no touchscreen support ),My application just hanged.

Since i am new to the BB development world , any help on how to make my application backward compatible with non touch screen device ,is appreciated..

faithfully 
Dharmesh

Comment: The models you specified (8520,8900,9630,9700) are all capable of running OS5. Only 8900 was released with an earlier OS 4.6.1. You do not need to remove touchscreen libraries from an application to run it on these OS5 models. To give you a useful answer I would need to see the errors you are getting an possibly some code.

Comment: after this error i have stopped working on that backward compatibility problem but now again i have started working on that prob and founded what's the problem. i was using jde 6.0 and it compiles cod with jde 6 library and scroll view is implemented in JDE 6 only and this all device i have mentioned supports till JDE 5 or os 5 so no scroll view support .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved .

it was a JDE compatibility error. changing a version of JDE has solved my probelm